# Facebook Counter for Blog - Not Changing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, counter

My website url: http://nagaratharkavadi.com/index.php/en/home

I have included Facebook Like for my blog. I have integrated the code manually (which was available as a module in Joomla) but problem is that the count is showing as "270K" and for each blog entry the count is showing the same. How can I resolve this?